# Using a heredoc as a hash value

Tags: ruby

I have a method `Embed.toggler` that takes a hash argument. With the following code, I'm trying to use a heredoc in the hash.

```
                Embed.toggler({
                    title: <<-RUBY 
                        #{entry['time']}
                        #{entry['group']['who']
                        #{entry['name']}
                    RUBY
                    content: content
                })
```

However, I'm getting the following error trace:

```
syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting tSTRING_DEND
                        content: content
                                ^
can't find string "RUBY" anywhere before EOF
syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting tSTRING_CONTENT or tSTRING_DBEG or tSTRING_DVAR or tSTRING_END
                        title: <<-RUBY 
                                      ^
```

How I can avoid getting this error?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @sawa how can I make the given code work and prevent the error.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Add a comma after your `<<-RUBY`:

```
Embed.toggler({
    title: <<-RUBY,
        #{entry['time']}
        #{entry['group']['who']
        #{entry['name']}
    RUBY
    content: content
})
```

> this does work in general. I am not sure why it wasn't working in my code though.

It didn't work because hashes require key/value pair to be separated by a comma, like `{title: 'my title', content: 'my content' }` and your code just didn't have the comma. It was hard to see that because of the cumbersome HEREDOC syntax.

> Do you know if there is a way to perform operations on the string?

You're playing with fire. It's always safer (and usually cleaner) to extract a variable and do post-processing on a variable itself:

```
title = <<-RUBY
   #{entry['time']}
   #{entry['group']['who']
   #{entry['name']}
RUBY

Embed.toggler(title: title.upcase, content: content)
```

However, if you feel dangerous today, you can just add operations after opening HEREDOC literal, just as you've added the comma:

```
Embed.toggler({
    title: <<-RUBY.upcase,
        #{entry['time']}
        #{entry['group']['who']
        #{entry['name']}
    RUBY
    content: content
})
```

But I discourage you from this because it destroys readability.

Comment: @sawa Well, I noticed the syntax error in posted code and thought that was the question :)

Comment: I noticed the syntax error too, but had no idea what the question was :) +1 from me.

Comment: this does work in general. I am not sure why it wasn't working in my code though. Do you know if there is a way to perform operations on the string? i.e. `{title: <<-TXT asd TXT.upcase}`

Comment: @AlexeyShein Sorry, I should have specified that I tried your fix, but the error was still appearing when I ran my app. I opened up irb and tried using a HEREDOC in a hash value (using your suggestion) and it worked. So i accepted your answer, but am still unsure why I it didn't work in my app.

Comment: @maxpleaner It seems you also miss `}` in `#{entry['group']['who']`.